How to count model objects in pytest-django?
While I'm perfectly able to get the objects count in python manage.py shell, somehow the test returns always 0.
What am I missing?
#myapp/test_.py
import pytest
from .models import Organization

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_organization():
    assert Organization.objects.count() == 10

$ pytest:
E       assert 0 == 10
E        +  where 0 = count()
E        +    where count = <django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x734e379b0790>.count
E        +      where <django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x734e379b0790> = Organization.objects


tests are using separate database which needs to be populated

The problem is not the test, the point is that tests run independently (or as much as possible), so each time you start a test, the database is basically emptied, etc. So the changes of one test do not occur in the next test.

run test, create db for test and delete test db when test end.
